# how to implement react-google-invisible-recaptcha in functional base component

Tags: reactjs, recaptcha

I have installed `react-google-invisible-recaptcha` from npm website. And i have read the documentation but they have provided documentation for class base component as you can see below

```
class Example extends React.Component {
constructor( props ) {
super( props );
this.state = { value: '' };
this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind( this );
this.onResolved = this.onResolved.bind( this );
}
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <input
      type="text"
      value={ this.state.value }
      onChange={ event => this.setState( { value: event.target.value } ) } />
    <button onClick={ this.onSubmit }>Submit</button>
    <Recaptcha
      ref={ ref => this.recaptcha = ref }
      sitekey="<sitekey>"
      onResolved={ this.onResolved } />
  </div>
   );
}
  onSubmit() {
  if ( '' == this.state.value ) {
    alert( 'Validation failed! Input cannot be empty.' );
    this.recaptcha.reset();
  } else {
   this.recaptcha.execute();
}
}
onResolved() {
alert( 'Recaptcha resolved with response: ' + this.recaptcha.getResponse() );
  }
 }
```

so there is no documentation for implementing it with functional base component...
how i can implement it with functional component????

Comment: Have you considered actually using one that's seemingly maintained and  providing hooks from the get-go? https://github.com/t49tran/react-google-recaptcha-v3

Comment: i want to use invisible-google-recaptcha not visible

Comment: Actually i want to implement react-google-invisible-recaptcha in functional base component???